# CG series about a beast planet

Tags: story-identification, tv, planets

I remember seeing this series back when I was in the early grades of primary school (prep to 3) so this would be between 1996 and 1999

from what I remember it was set in space and the cast was made up from people from these different worlds, one of the characters is from a fire attributed world and I get the impression he was small framed (I think).

at one point in the series this entity appears called the Beast Planet appears, the one scene I do remember is that this Beast Planet attacks the fire planet, the front of the beast planet opens up with this claw and grabs the fire planet from bellow and then the fire planet is slammed into the beast planet dooming the fire planet but I think the beast planet was unharmed.

I also seem to remember that the cast discover the other planets have engines which allows the remaining planets to escape from the Beast Planet rather than them being sitting ducks.

I remember that this beast planet, despite being called a beast is actually more machine. I began remembering this series after playing Galaxy Angel where I saw the [Black Moon](http://galaxyangel.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Moon) and it reminds me of this beast planet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the US this was called War Planets but apparently the original name was [Shadow Raiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Raiders).

Here's the Beast Planet attacking another planet, getting ready to grapple it.

[image]

The hero was a Rock planet guy named Graveheart.

[image]

Other planets had different species like the Ice people

[image]

and Fire people.

[image]

Here's the intro from Youtube:

I kinda dug this show considering it was for kids.